# Cannot scrape Covid-19 data from web table

Tags: python, web

I'm doing some research on spread of Covid-19 across Kosovo using Python.
The problem is that the result got from web scraping on the table is empty.
The web is https://corona-ks.info/?lang=en
Table from which I need records:

[image]

I have used many ways to extract the record but without success, latest code used is just for Headings is:

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://corona-ks.info/?lang=en'
# get web data
req = requests.get(link)
# parse web data
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")
th = soup.find_all('th')
table = soup.find('table')

headings = []
for item in th: 
    item = (item.text).rstrip("\n")
    headings.append(item)
print(headings)
```

result:

```
['', '', '', '', '']
```

Got the same empty list also for the table.

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: Show us the code for scraping.

Comment: My guess is that there is something wrong with the code you used to do the web scraping. But it's kinda hard to tell without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger and look at the call made when viewing this https://corona-ks.info/?lang=en you'd see it making a call to get JSON data from `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bgeVam/Kosovo-Coronatracker-Data/master/data.json` to populate the table. Instead of trying to scrape the table, why don't you use the same JSON the corona-ks.info is using?

Also, in addition to the data source I mentioned above, I saw a couple others it was also using:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bgeVam/Kosovo-Coronatracker-Data/master/municipality.json
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bgeVam/Kosovo-Coronatracker-Data/master/kosovoMap.json

Comment: Thnx a lot buddy, this is great.